# Cardinality of field completion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complete-spaces

Let $K$ be the completion of a field $k$ equipped with a norm $\|\cdot\|$. What can we say about it's cardinality, $|K|$?

By Cantor's completion process we can treat $K$ as a quotient of $c \le k^\infty$ (space of convergent sequences) by $c_0$, space of null sequences. So definitely $|K| \le |k|^{\aleph_0}$. Is the inequality with flipped sign also true?

Sometimes yes ($k = \mathbb R$). Would an assumption that $k = K$ help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a field $k$ has continuum cardinality, then its completion $K$
>   has continuum cardinality as well, that's $|k|=|K|$.

This is just because $|k|=2^{\aleph_0}$ hence
\begin{align}
|K|
&\leq |k^{\mathbb N}|\\
&=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}\\
&=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}\\
&=2^{\aleph_0}\\
&=|k|
\end{align}
because $\aleph_0\times\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.
Since $K$ contains $k$, clearly $|K|\geq |k|$ hence we get $|K|=|k|$.

For example, if $k=\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ the algebraic closure of the field of $p$-adic number, which has continuum cardinality, then its completion $\Omega_p$ has continuum cardinality as well.

On the other hand, if $k=\mathbb Q$ then its completion $K=\Bbb R$ or $K=\Bbb Q_p$ has cardinality strictly greater than $k$.